# Expected value of number of ice-cream cones

Tags: probability, expected-value

The father promised his daughter to buy from 2 to 5 ice-cream cones. To determine how many cones he will buy, he tosses a coin 3 times, counts the number of heads and adds 2 to that number. What is the expected value of the number of cones?

**My solution**:

Let $X = {0, 1, 2, 3}$ - the number of heads. Then $C = {2, 3, 4, 5}$ is the number of cones that the father may buy. $P(X = 0, 1, 2, 3) = {1/8, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8}, P(C = 2, 3, 4, 5) = {1/8, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8}$.

Then $EC = 2 * 1/8 + 3 * 1/2 + 4 * 1/4 + 5 * 1/8 = 1/4 + 3/2 + 1 + 5/8 = 2/8 + 12/8 + 8/8 + 5/8 = 27/8$.

However, I was told that this answer is wrong.

Where is the mistake and how to solve that problem?

Comment: As the expected number of Heads in three tosses of a fair coin is $1.5$ the answer to your question must be $3.5$

Comment: Your calculation assumes that it is more likely that you get exactly one Head then that  you get exactly two, but this is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The probabilities of getting $0,1,2,3$ are slightly off. The change of getting $1$ or $2$ times head is equal. You can see this by writing out the possibilities:

$$HHH, \ HHT, \ HTH,  \ HTT,  \ THH,  \ THT,  \ TTH,  \ TTT$$

Or by noting that the change of a number of times head should equal the change of number of times tails. If you have 1 times head, you have 2 times tails. So

$$P(X=0,1,2,3)=\frac{1}{8}, \frac{3}{8}, \frac{3}{8}, \frac{1}{8}$$